# The pose bone matrix is reset to an incorrect value

Tags: python, bones

I try to set pose bone matrices for setting location and rotation for bones, like this:

```
current_pose_bone.matrix = relative_matrix
```

The first matrix is assigned normally, but for some reason the second is not, the value is reset to incorrect, why does this happen?

**First matrix (correct):**

```
Matrix(((0.3579, -0.3624, -0.8606, 0.3231)
        (0.1733,  0.9314, -0.3201, 0.2978)
        (0.9175, -0.0346,  0.3962, 0.0259)
        (0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000)))

>>> C.active_bone.parent.matrix.inverted() @ C.active_bone.matrix
Matrix(((0.35792356729507446, -0.3623908758163452, -0.8605601787567139, 0.323106050491333),
    (0.17334483563899994, 0.9313840866088867, -0.32011792063713074, 0.29777100682258606),
    (0.917519748210907, -0.03459606319665909, 0.3961828649044037, 0.025910720229148865),
    (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))
```

**Second matrix (not correct):**

```
Matrix(((0.3579, -0.3624, -0.8606,  0.3231),
        (-0.1733, -0.9314,  0.3201, -0.2980),
        ( 0.9175, -0.0346,  0.3962,  0.0259),
        ( 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  1.0000)))

>>> C.active_bone.parent.matrix.inverted() @ C.active_bone.matrix
Matrix(((-0.07111173868179321, -0.36239081621170044, 0.9293095469474792, 0.3231060802936554),
    (-0.009380493313074112, -0.9313840270042419, -0.3639175593852997, -0.2980000972747803),
    (0.9974243640899658, -0.034596025943756104, 0.06283299624919891, 0.025910764932632446),
    (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))
```